# how to switch off / on indexing in a web page

Tags: solr, nutch, apache-tika

I'm using Nutch 1.6 and Solr 4.3 on Ubuntu Server 12.04
I would like to switch on and off content indexing. Is there a way to specify this behaviour in my HTML pages so that Solr can behave accordingly ?

As an example, when using Google Search Appliance I would use "googleon" - "googleoff" tags around the content on the page that i don't want indexed (headers, footers, copyright strings, etc ).

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wil need to create a custom plugin for Nutch to be able to accomplish this behavior. Below are some relevant links with examples.

- [Apache nutch: Manipulating the DOM before parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576735/apache-nutch-manipulating-the-dom-before-parsing)
- [Precise data extraction with Apache Nutch](http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/)

Comment: The second link is very clear in what needs to happen. I have an implementation just like it to target custom tags injected by our template system so I imagine writing a similar plugin will do the trick for you, Zander.

Comment: Thank you Paige and Claude. Will try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is a text file, "robots.txt" that provide information to the search engines about which html pages the program is allowed or not to look for content. In the link [FAQ robots.txt: How to stop indexing](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html) you will find all the information.

Comment: that file controls crawlers' activity in the web folder it is placed. Instead, I'm referring to a way to control indexing inside a page with tags (please google for the tags googleoff / googleon for more details)